# Handlebars Each Helper scope is changes property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi I am using EmberJS in my application and this is my Application-Template and and Application Controller

I have a property in controller called isEditAble ,But I have an issue
If i used to check this property in outside of each helper , this will execute fine.
But if i used inside a each helper (isEditAble Property) scope is not looking inside and it is always going to be false.

Could anybody please guide on this how to use property inside a each helper.

ApplicationTemplate:

```
   //This if executing and textbox is displaying because of isEditAble = true
   {{#if isEditAble}}
        <div style="width: 40px;">
        {{input type=text disabled=isChecked}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}


{{#each checkBoxes}}
      //This if is NOT executing and checkboxes is  NOT displaying
      //Even Though is EditAble true
     {{#if isEditAble}}
        <div style="width: 40px;">
        {{input type=checkbox disabled=isChecked}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Apllication Controller:

```
 App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Tag Editor',
  checkBoxes: [
    {id: 1, isChecked: true},
    {id: 2, isChecked: true},
    {id: 3, isChecked: true},
   {id: 4, isChecked: true}
  ],
  isEditAble: true
  });
```

Comment: Could you specify which the version of emberjs?

Comment: i am using emberJS 1.5.1

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [block parameters](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/08/ember-1-9-0-released.html#toc_block-params) to properly scope the values:

```
{{#each checkBoxes as |cbox|}}
     {{#if isEditAble}}
        <div>
        {{input type="checkbox" checked=cbox.isChecked}} hello
        </div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Also notice how type is wrapped in quotes (and also I think that `isChecked` should toggle the `checked` property instead of `disabled`).

[JSbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huzera/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

edit: As you are using an older version v1.5.1., block parameters aren't available. You can access the parent context by using

```
 {{#if ../isEditAble}}
```

or the root context (which in this case is the same as the parent context) with

```
{{#if @root.isEditAble}}
```

Comment: I tried to use  |cbox|                                                                                      i am getting parse Error  Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 7:
...}{{#each checkBoxes as |cBox|}} {{/each}}

Comment: Ah, okay, v1.5.1. is quite old and doesn't have blockparameters. See my edit to access parent context on older versions.